# how to make the map clusters larger distance in less dense area in map instead of showing markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, jquery-plugins

I am using google map(clustering version) from the following link:

[google map clusterer](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-clustering.html)

everything is good and for example when I have 1000 location it clusters them but when I have 200 location and density is  not high it does not clusters. I want to clusters even those that are not dense what should I do? is there anyway that I can change level of sensitivity of this google map to distance and zoom to be able to cluster even  markers in a less dense area?

Comment: You can check the [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclustererplus/docs/reference.html). There are parameters such as `gridSize` and `minimumClusterSize` that you can play with to obtain the desired results.

Comment: Thanks for answring in documentation it does not say how to use it. I added them like this but I get an error:                              $(this).gmap('addMarker', { 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(southWest.lat() + latSpan * Math.random(), southWest.lng() + lngSpan * Math.random()) } ).click(function() {
        $('#map_canvas').gmap('openInfoWindow', { content : 'Hello world!' }, this);
       }).setMinimumClusterSize(2);

Comment: How do you create the marker cluster? You can pass options in the constructor. Let me add an answer below with some code...

Comment: Documentation Link and google map clusterer link is not good. Please update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you figured out which parameters to use with the above comments, here is how to pass these params to your marker cluster constructor:

```
var mcOptions = {
    gridSize: 50,
    minimumClusterSize: 10
};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Where `map` is your map object and `markers` is your markers array. The numbers used are only for example. You have to play with these to get the desired results. Hope this helps.

Comment: What kind of units are those numbers?

Comment: @Adam Pixels. It's in the docs. *The grid size of a cluster in pixels. The grid is a square.*

Comment: Thank you. Which docs are you referring to? I believe the API has changed and there is no mcOptions parameter anymore https://www.npmjs.com/package/@googlemaps/markerclusterer

Comment: This answer was provided over 8 years ago. I am **not** the maintainer of this library. If the current documentation is unclear, please ask for clarifications on their Github.

Comment: Yes, I know. Google owns the package. After commenting on your answer, I realized that mcOptions is no longer in use. So now I may have to create a new question at SO.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking for this in 2023:

[js-markerclusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-markerclusterer) accepts `algorithmOptions` in `MarkerClusterer` constructor which isn't documented anywhere.
Use it like this:

```
const clusterer = new MarkerClusterer({
    map,
    markers: allMarkers,
    algorithmOptions: { radius: 120 },
})
```

The default algorithm that MarkerClusterer uses is [supercluster](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster), look [here](https://github.com/mapbox/supercluster#options) for available `algorithmOptions`

There is a TypeScript error when passing those options because it isn't typed well and suspects only maxZoom property. To get rid of this error you can do something like this:

```
import { MarkerClusterer, SuperClusterOptions } from '@googlemaps/markerclusterer'

const clusterer = new MarkerClusterer({
    map,
    markers: allMarkers,
    algorithmOptions: { radius: 120 } as SuperClusterOptions,
})
```

Answer (score -2):

**Swift**

cluster size change worked for me this way in the latest version and its **super easy**

```
    // Set up the cluster manager with the supplied icon generator and
    // renderer.
    let iconGenerator = GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator()
    let algorithm = GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm()
    let renderer = GMUDefaultClusterRenderer(mapView: mapView,
                                             clusterIconGenerator: iconGenerator)
    renderer.delegate = self
    renderer.minimumClusterSize = 5 // Here is the setting

    clusterManager = GMUClusterManager(map: mapView, algorithm: algorithm,
                                       renderer: renderer)
    clusterManager.setDelegate(self, mapDelegate: self)
```